# Open the url with Access Token which comes in API response

Tags: python, django, rest, api

I have a set of api calls which can be accessible by Access Token and I'm able to get responses from the apis but one of the responses contain URL but when I try to access it, url asks for Log in which i'm already Logged in because thats how I got Access Token.

API response:

```
{
"root": "some value",
    "blocks": {
        "some value": {
            "display_name": "some display name",
            "block_id": "abc123",
            "view_url": "https://www.abc.come",
            "web_url": "https://www.abv.com",
            "type": "some type",
            "id": "some id"
        }
    }
}
```

So from this response I want to access "web_url" so when i do a Get request, it asks for Log in.
So how can I access web_url without Log in ?

Comment: Have a look at what happens when you follow this work flow in your browser. Maybe you need to send your access token with every request, maybe you need to send something in your header... Your question is vague and without details of the website, we can't help you.

Comment: i'm using access token for all the api requests and the url which i am accessing is edx. So if access web_url from browser it asks for Log in and thats fine but if use postman or something then also it asks for Log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the url from the response using the access token

```
access_token = "your_access_token"
web_url_response = requests.get(response['blocks']['some value']['web_url'], headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
```

Comment: what is the "response" there?

Comment: It is the API response you got(shown in your question)

Comment: I got the response and its a html page but its not taking me inside the page but asking for log in